# Selenium/java-xpath for xlink:href attribute

Tags: selenium, svg, xpath

I tried to locate `use` element with attribute value `'#aaa'` for below snippet

```
<svg>
    <use xlink:href='#aaa'></use>
</svg>
```

I was able to locate using css selector `use[* |href='#aaa']` . But I require it in xpath. I tried below xpath but it is not working

```
(//*[name()='use'])[ * ='#aaa' or @href='#aaa']
```

Note :I need to use the value `'#aaa'` to differentiate from other elements.

Could anyone please help to construct this xpath.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your predicate `[ * ='#aaa' or @href='#aaa']` returns `false` as there is no attribute as `href` (but `xlink:href`), and `use` has no child nodes with text content `'#aaa'`.

Note that wild-card for *any attribute* is `@*` while just `*` is for *any node (except attribute)*. Try below XPath

```
"//*[name()='use' and @*='#aaa']"
```

Comment: FYI: This works for selenium in  c# as well

Answer (score 2):

For XPath:

```
//*[name()='use'][contains(@*, '#aaa')]
```

Or variant provided by **Andersson**

Approaches with `[@xlink:href='#aaa']` don't work on practice

Answer (score 2):

as none of the suggestions really worked for me, I came up with following (tested in chrome devtools):

```
//*[name()='use' and @*[contains(.,'#aaa)]]
```

comments:

- name()='use'

  - because a normal tag search (i.e //use) did not work
- @*[contains(.,'#aaa')]

  - because contains with a wildcard (i.e. contains(@*,'#aaa')) didn't work

Answer (score 1):

lookout, if someone needs contains..

```
"//*[name()='use'][contains(@*='#aaa')]"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an SVG tag and it works a little differently

Please try below xpath:

```
//[local-name()='svg']/yourxpath
```

Comment: Could you please let me know whether it works or not

Comment: It does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the xpath

```
//use[@xlink:href='#aaa']
```

or

```
//use[contains(@xlink:href,'#aaa')]
```

Comment: both suggestions end up invalid xpath expression

Answer (score 0):

As the element is within `svg` namespace you can use the following `xpath`:

```
//*[name()="svg"]/use[contains(@xlink:href,'#aaa')]
```