# Get SVG Xlink:Href Selenium - Python

Tags: python, selenium, svg, xpath

I'm trying to get the link from all elements on a page with the below code, using selenium/python.

```
<svg preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="svg svg--messages svg-icon valign--middle" role="img">

<use xlink:href="#icon-messages--small"></use></svg>
```

As it doesn't contain an A link (it's an SVG with embedded XLINK) - this exhausts my knowledge. I've had a look around and I believe selecting the XPATH could work but I can't seem to grab the correct one with all my testing.

I have seen this answer too: [Selenium/java-xpath for xlink:href attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46273093/selenium-java-xpath-for-xlinkhref-attribute)

So I tried:

```
for a in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[name()='use' and @*='#icon-messages--small']"):
            link2 = a.get_attribute('href')
            l.append(link2)
```

But it doesn't seem to help in my case?

Any help would be fantastic!

Comment: Show how you tried

Comment: for a in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[name()='use' and @*='#icon-messages--small']"):
            link2 = a.get_attribute('href')
            l.append(link2)

Comment: Change from `a.get_attribute('href')` to `a.get_attribute('xlink:href')`

Answer (score 0):

You **can not** extract links from these elements since they are **not** containing links. As you mentioned by yourself.
You do can extract the `xlink:href` attribute values, `#icon-messages--small` for this specific element. To do so you will need to locate uniquely all the elements you want to extract that attribute from them.
Obviously it is possible, but to do so we need to see the entire XML of that page, however you did not share this data.

Comment: All the elements on the page I am looking for the links of have this exact same code, would I be able to scrape all of it? 

It's just a meetup.com attendees list and I'm looking to grab the link behind the message SVG button.

Comment: Again: the links are **not** inside the elements. You can't extract them because they are not contained there.